# Automation through Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, automation

I want to convert one trigger to Process Builder which is on update only. So, can I create process builder action for update only instead of created or edited.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a process that runs 'when a record is created or edited', then set your criteria for executing the actions to 'Formula evaluates to true' with a formula of `NOT(ISNEW())`. This will prevent your actions being run when a new record is created.

Answer (score 0):

Process Builder provide only two events type viz.

1. on create
2. On create or edit

Process created by process builder executes after trigger execution, so even if you call Apex method from process, it will not get trigger context to know whether it is update call or insert call.